# Programa em C não lê valores em arquivo de txt

Tags: c, c++, visual-studio, fopen

Galera, de novo estou de volta. Apliquei algumas mudanças que os membros daqui sugeriram em um outro post, porém os valores continuam sem ser lidos da forma correta. Agora da até uns valores inteiros (antes o DOS imprimia valores negativos com mais de 5 algarismos). Segue parte do código:

```
void (CPU)
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
int matriiz_A[5][5];
char matriz_A[5][5];
int matriz_B[3][2];
int matriz_C[3][2];
int m, n, k, l, i, j, x, aux;

printf("\n Abaixo temos a matriz A \n");

FILE *matrizA;
matrizA = fopen("matriz_A.txt", "r");

if (matrizA == NULL)
{
    printf("\nNão foi possivel abrir o arquivo. \n");
    exit(0);
}

while (fgets(matriz_A, 25, matrizA) != NULL);
{
    for (m = 0; m<5; m++)
    {
        for (n = 0; n<5; n++)
        {
            fscanf(matrizA," %d%*c ", &matriz_A[m][n]);
            printf(" %d ", matriz_A[m][n]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
fclose(matrizA);
system("pause");
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
char escolha = '0';

printf("\nEm que modo você deseja executar o programa? \n");
printf("(1) CPU \n");
printf("(2) GPU \n");
printf("Qualquer outra tecla fecha o programa \n");
escolha = getche();

if (escolha == '1')
{
    CPU();
}
else if (escolha == '2')
{

}
else if ((escolha != '1') && (escolha != '2'))
{
    printf("\nEscolha inválida. Programa será encerrado\n");
    exit(1);
}

//system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Segue abaixo o arquivo .txt que quero ler:

```
01 00 02 03 04
00 05 06 00 07
08 09 00 11 12
13 00 14 15 00
00 00 16 17 18
```

O resultado que obtive foi este:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

usando aux eu também obtive o mesmo resultado. Seria algum problema com a função getche()? Isso pq eu percebi que no Linux ela fazia sair lixo na matriz, já no windows não. Pesquisei a fundo na net e nao solucionei ainda. :(

Comment: Se a solução que as pessoas apresentaram a você no seu outro post não resolveu o seu problema, você deveria ter exposto isso a elas nos comentários das respostas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como o programa postado está confuso, é mais fácil reescrever do que apontar os erros.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void CPU(void)
{
  int m, n, nLido;

  char matriz_A[5][5];

  FILE* matrizA;

  printf("* abrindo arquivo matriz_A.txt\n");

  matrizA = fopen("matriz_A.txt", "r");
  if (matrizA == NULL)
  {
    printf("* nao foi possivel abrir arquivo matriz_A.txt\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  for (m = 0; m < 5; m++)
  {
    for (n = 0; n < 5; n++)
    {
      nLido = fscanf(matrizA,"%d", &matriz_A[m][n]);
      if (nLido != 1)
      {
        printf(" erro na leitura de matriz_A[%d][%d]\n", m, n);
        exit(2);
      }
      printf("%02d ", matriz_A[m][n]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  fclose(matrizA);
}

int main(void)
{
  char escolha = '0';

  printf("*\n");
  printf("* em que modo você deseja executar o programa?\n");
  printf("* (1) CPU \n");
  printf("* (2) GPU \n");
  printf("* qualquer outra tecla fecha o programa\n");
  scanf(" %c%*[^\n]", &escolha);

  if (escolha == '1')
  {
    CPU();
  }
  else if (escolha == '2')
  {

  }
  else
  {
    printf("* escolha invalida, programa encerrado\n");
    exit(3);
  }

}

// 01 00 02 03 04
// 00 05 06 00 07
// 08 09 00 11 12
// 13 00 14 15 00
// 00 00 16 17 18
```

Teste:

```
[~/Projects/testes/so]
$cc -o 387091 387091.c 

[~/Projects/testes/so]
$./387091
*
* em que modo você deseja executar o programa?
* (1) CPU 
* (2) GPU 
* qualquer outra tecla fecha o programa
1
* abrindo arquivo matriz_A.txt
01 00 02 03 04 
00 05 06 00 07 
08 09 00 11 12 
13 00 14 15 00 
00 00 16 17 18 

[~/Projects/testes/so]
$
```

Comment: obrigado, mano. Solucionou. Alem de me servir, poderei estudar o código e me aperfeiçoar na linguagem

Answer (score 0):

Faça:

```
void (CPU)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    int matriz_A[5][5];
    int matriz_B[3][2];
    int matriz_C[3][2];
    char linha[300];
    int m, n, k, l, i, j, x, aux;

    printf("\n Abaixo temos a matriz A \n");

    FILE *matrizA;
    matrizA = fopen("matriz_A.txt", "r");

    if (matrizA == NULL)
    {
         printf("\nNão foi possivel abrir o arquivo. \n");
         exit(0);
    }
    m =0;
    while (fgets(linha, 300, matrizA) != NULL);
    {
        for (n = 0; n<5; n++)
        {
            sscanf(linha," %d%*c ", &matriz_A[m][n]);
            printf(" %d ", matriz_A[m][n]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        m++;
    }
    fclose(matrizA);
    system("pause");
}
```

ou

```
void (CPU)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    int matriz_A[5][5];
    int matriz_B[3][2];
    int matriz_C[3][2];
    int m, n, k, l, i, j, x, aux;

    printf("\n Abaixo temos a matriz A \n");

    FILE *matrizA;
    matrizA = fopen("matriz_A.txt", "r");

    if (matrizA == NULL)
    {
         printf("\nNão foi possivel abrir o arquivo. \n");
         exit(0);
    }

    for (m = 0; m<5; m++)
    {
        for (n = 0; n<5; n++)
        {
            fscanf(matrizA," %d%*c ", &matriz_A[m][n]);
            printf(" %d ", matriz_A[m][n]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(matrizA);
    system("pause");
}
```

Como tinha sido orientado em sua outra questão.

Comment: não é necessário colocar assim "%d%*c ", apenas "%d" é suficiente, porque o formato "%d" pula "whitespaces", isto é, espaços, '\n', '\r' e '\t'